# What would be the most significant way to farm neural sensors in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

I've been on a crafting spree in Warframe, and a lot of the things that I am trying to make require 2 at most, which doesn't seem like a lot, but when they are rare drops, it makes it a hassle. Any help would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You'll want to bring one or more of the following frames:**

- Nekros built for Desecrate

  - Max efficiency, max range
- Hydroid built for Pilfering Swarm (Augment, can be purchased from Syndicates)

  - Max efficiency, max strength, max range

**Bring them to the nodes:**

- Themisto, Jupiter (Assassination)

  - Once Zanuka and Alad V have been killed it's usually a chance between getting Alloy Plates (ugh) or getting Neural Sensors (drops in 1x - 2x)
- Sinai, Jupiter (Dark Sector Survival)

  - Infested
  - Ideal with a party, but also soloable, just make sure to move around often to trigger as much spawns as possible.
- Elara, Jupiter (Survival)

  - Corpus
  - The difference between Elara and Sinai is the mobs on Elara are typically much quicker and easier to kill in the initial time spent in the map.  Sinai mobs start off around 25-30, making Elara a popular choice for Hydroid Pilfering Swarm users.

Comment: Add Raptor assassination to the list. Neural sensors don't drop on Europa, but they do from Raptor. And some people say they drop more often than from Alad.

Comment: If you bring those two frames, plus an Energy Vampire Trinity to keep power up, you'll do much better.  I took a Nekros, Pilfering Hydroid and Trinity to the Survival mission listed.  We were all running resource boosters and we had 60 or so by 20 minutes.  I have had less than favorable results with Dark Sector farming.

Answer (score 2):

Dark Sectors and Survival missions on Jupiter are the best (stated prior by JoJo) *especially* the Dark Sectors. Jupiter's normal survival run can yield 2-4 NS per 20 minute run generally without any boosters from my experience, but some report higher output is possible; also noticeable, the larger your team the better the chance for NS drop and at higher yields, so team up and try for 20 minute runs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Neural_Sensors), they are a rare drop on Jupiter, and can thus be found in lockers, boxes, dropped from enemies, you name it, although apparently are far more likely to be acquired from the Alad V Assassination mission "Themisto", Dark Sector defence "Sinai", and corpus survival "Elara" sectors.